# Fetch new Mails (Also from Subfolders) from another IMAP server as new Mail in Postfix

Tags: postfix, email

everyone. I have installed Postfix on a server with Aliases and Domains from a MySQL Database.

It is configured to forward some adresses to other Mail Accounts and also delivers some mails in local mailboxes that will be queried over a dovecot imap server.

For this example let there be two users:

- `forwarded@domain.com` what is a user that gets its mail just forwarded to let's say `forwarded@forwarded-host.com`
- `local@domain.com` what is a user that accesses its mail from local IMAP.

Now, I want to fetch some Mails from another mailserver and handle them as if they were sent to a user of my Mailserver.

Lets say those corelations exist:

- `forwarded@domain.com` has two external accounts: `user-a@externaldomain.com` and `user-a@some-other-company.com`
- `local@domain.com` has also one external account `user-b@externaldomain.com`

The Problem is the new mails on that other Mailserver is not always in the inbox, it might be in subdirectories: `mailinglists/all` or `mailinglists/it` but also in `mailinglists/some-other-department` which is not interesting and should not be delivered.

I already found a programm called `fetchmail` but I cannot find how to fetch subdirectories or decide which subdirectories are fetched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the folder option. Just put it in the fetchmail config file (Default is .fetchmailrc).

```
poll mail.server.com protocol IMAP
    user 'xxx@xxx,com'
    password 'xxxxxx'
    folder 'mailinglist'
```

See [man page](http://www.catb.org/~esr/fetchmail/fetchmail-man.html) or search for "fetchmail folder option" if you need more examples.

Comment: Will I repeat the "folder" part per folder, I want to sync or do I need to repeat the whole poll part?

Comment: Have you had a look at the man page? (Keyword: folder[s]) Causes a specified non-default mail folder on the mailserver **(or comma-separated list of folders)** to be retrieved. The syntax of the folder name is server-dependent. This option is not available under POP3, ETRN, or ODMR.